# scroll only center part of a grid from entire page

Tags: html, css, scroll

in the example below how to scroll `.b` wherever pointer is placed - inside `.a` or `.c` - so outside of `.b`

```css
.wrap{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:15fr 70fr 15fr;
height:50vh;
}
.a, .c{overflow:hidden; background:orange;}
.b{overflow-y:scroll; background:lightblue;}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
<div class='a'></div>
<div class='b'>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br></div>
<div class='c'></div>
</div>
```